# PHP Button to call function will cause function to be repeated if page refreshed

Tags: php

I have two simple HTML form buttons that call PHP functions to send emails now. Everything works fine except for one thing.  If one of the buttons is clicked to send a report, and then the page is refreshed, the function seemed to be called again and the emails well go out again with a page refresh by a user using a browser refresh button.

If the page is refreshed, the email will go out again for the last button clicked.   So, if I click on Button 1 and then refresh the page, I will get two reports for button 1.  If I click on button #1, and then click on Button #2, only the second report will go out.  If I click on button #2 and then #1, only Report #1 will go out again.

So, no matter how many buttons are clicked, refreshing the page will cause the last button click (only to repeat).   Trying to unset the request parameter (in code below) has no effect all on the repeats caused by a page refresh.

I don't understand why (on a Page Refresh) the page is seeing the last button click made as set, and why the unset command is not working.

Thanks for any help.

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['email_this_weeks_report'] )) {
    unset($_REQUEST['email_last_weeks_report']);
    #send email now email code for this week

}    
if( isset( $_REQUEST['email_last_weeks_report'] )) {
    unset($_REQUEST['email_last_weeks_report']);
    #send email now email code for last week

}

<form>          
    <input class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" type="submit"
 name="email_this_weeks_report" value="Email This Weeks Report Now" />
</form> 

<form>          
    <input class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" type="submit"
 name="email_last_weeks_report" value="Email Last Weeks Report Now" />
</form>
```

Comment: You are unsetting the same thing in both `if` conditions

Comment: _“I don't understand why (on a Page Refresh) the page is seeing the last button click made as set”_ - because the browser makes the exact same request again ... that is what a refresh _means_. _“and why the unset command is not working”_ - because it is nonsense to begin with. It would do the same unsetting the _first_ time you send the form - so if that _did_ work as you thought, it would break your functionality from the very beginning. You are trying to _differentiate_ between two requests that are _identical_ ... of course that can’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking the button submits the form.

The data in the form is bundled up and included in the request.

Aside: You're using `method=GET`, the default, but you're not making a "safe" request. You are *doing* something, not just *getting* information. You should use a POST request.

When you click refresh, you tell the browser to make the request again and display a new version of the page.

Since the request includes the query string which says "send a particular email", it sends that email again.

---

Unsetting values in `$_REQUEST` has no effect because when the browser makes a *new* request with the same data in it: `$_REQUEST` just gets filled up again.

---

You should deal with this by using [the PRG pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get):

1. Submit the form using `method=POST`
2. Have your PHP script process the data in the form (i.e. send the email) then **redirect** to a different PHP script
3. Have the new PHP script display the result (in this case there is no result, its just the form, you could use a plain HTML document with no PHP in it).

Comment: Is there no way to redirect to the same page or stay on the same page?   It seems annoying to have to build a landing page just to get around this and force the user to click back.    Adding the redirect back to the current does ask if you want to re-subit as well saly:   header("Location: export_current_week.php", true, 301);
  exit();

Comment: I ended up liking doing it this way better and just going to a "successfully emailed" notice page with a link to go back.   It's simple to remember and understand for me without overcomplicating things really.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<form>
```

To

```
<form method='POST'>
```

A simple way to prevent multiple submissions is to add a random token to the form in a hidden input.

```
<input type='hidden' name='formtoken' value='<?= uniqueid() ?>'/>
```

Every time the page is fetched from the server, the value of this hidden variable will change.  So on the server side, you can prevent the same form being resubmitted by checking whether a form with this unique ID has been submitted before.

```
session_start();
$sessionToken = $_SESSION['formtoken']? : null;
$currentToken = $_POST['formtoken']? : null;

// If no session token yet: form has never been submitted
if(!$sessionToken): 
  // save the current token in session so we'll recognize it next time
  $_SESSION['formtoken'] = $currentToken;
  /* ok to send the email */

// ElseIf current token was already used: Duplicate form submission
elseif($sessionToken === $currentToken): 
  /* don't send the email!*/

// Else session token exists, but current token is new: User fetched a new form from server
else:
  // update the session token
  $_SESSION['formtoken'] = $currentToken;
  /* ok to send the email */

endif;
```

When the user refreshes, the browser will ask if she wants to re-submit the form. If she does, you will know because the current token and the session token will be the same. It's up to you to decide how to handle it.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. It just encourages the browser to ask the user if they really want to refresh the page when they click refresh.

Comment: Yeah that was the behavior I got.  If you refresh the page the browser asks if you want to resubmit or cancel

Comment: @Reno This is standard behavior if a form posts to the same page it's on. The confirmation request serves its purpose though: it prevents a user unknowingly resending the email. You could post to a different page if you want to avoid even this confirmation, or add checks to prevent duplicate submissions. I've added a check to prevent duplicate submission here.

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing a page with a GET or a POST form will resubmit the data (albeit it will ask you first in the POST scenario, which you should use by the way).

Try redirecting the user after form submit

```
if( isset(...) ){
    // Do your logic
    header('Location: https://you_site.com/your-form-page?thank-you');
    exit;
}
```

This must be done before anything else is outputted on the page.

Comment: It isn't a POST form.

Comment: People in other replies are saying that making the form into POST will solve the issue. Was referring to that.

Comment: Answers should answer the question, they shouldn't be responses to other answers.